# Object Not Initialized

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Creating a server-side X++ class.

Everything works fine when the class is set to run on "Called From" or "Client", but if I change it to "Server" (which is what our client wants) I receive an error message that objects are not initialized.

In this case, "ListIterator is not intialized"

```
public static void myMethod(list _keyValuePairs)
{
    ListIterator keyValueIterator;

    keyValueIterator = new ListIterator (_keyValuePairs);
    while (keyValueIterator.more())
    {
        //do things here
        keyValueIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Brad, share some piece of code.

Comment: What I can think is, you are trying to initialize an ieterator for a list which is on client or something like this.

Comment: A client form calls the class.  The list is being passed to the class, so I would assume passing the list would effectively transfer it to the server.

Comment: Then, I am sure, you are getting a null value in List.

Comment: Check, by if (_keyValuePairs != null) { code to initialize ieterator }

Comment: It is empty.  I am guessing it can't pull the _keyValuePairs object from the lower client tier.  Will see if I can serialize it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have a idea. I will tell you if your issue hasnt been resolved yet

Comment: I passed in a packed list from the client method, and everything works now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this problem usually occurs if the [pack/unpack pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa879675.aspx)  that is used to transfer class attributes from one tier to the other was not implemented for the class. Your comments indicate the same (initialization on client, execution on server).

Comment: I used myList.pack() to pass it in and List::create() to deserialize it.  That works nicely.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try Enumerator like this:

```
List list = new List(Types::Integer);
Enumerator en ;
list.addEnd(333333); // add the value at last
list.addEnd(111111);
list.addEnd(222222);
en = list.getEnumerator();
print list.elements(); //"print number of element"

while (en.moveNext())
{
print en.current();
}
pause;
```

Source: https://msdax.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/list-class/